# West is /a/ direction, but is it /one/ direction?

Tags: cryptic-clues, cryptic-crosswords

I want to clue the letters "FOWEST". Clearly,

> Return of direction

would be fair, and so, IMO, is

> Return of a direction

but is it fair to make the slight change to

> Return of One Direction

which massively improves the surface? Or would you expect that to be "FOIWEST"?

Comment: A reminder that comments on whether the return of One Direction is a good or bad thing are off-topic unless they're hilarious.

Comment: 1. "FOWEST" is not, as far as I know, a word or the concatenation of words. If I were trying to solve a crossword, and found out this was one of the "words", I would feel cheated 2. Crossword clues generally don't have words other than the first one capitalized, so capitalizing "One Direction" implies that it's a proper noun.

Comment: @RupertMorrish I think you just allowed all comments on the return of One Direction

Answer (score 6):

I don't see any problems with this construction -- I've seen "one ___" meaning "a specific instance of ___" before, both in straight crosswords and in cryptics. For example, this clue from [The Crypt](http://aframegames.com/store/?download=the-crypt):

> One way to sing “Beat It” (4)

has the answer

> SCAT, as a double definition.

This seems like the construction you're talking about, just not embedded in a larger clue.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the clue would have the number of letters in the answer as part of the clue, so FOIWEST would be eliminated. Mind you, neither are proper words anyway.

If this is a clue for just a set of letters, this won't apply, but you could have been cluing NEWEST or similar in which case this is a point in order.

Also, unless the answer is One Direction related (by which I assume you are refering to the band) it is like a red herring that is past it's sell-by date and beginning to smell a bit.

Comment: It needs some additional letters added before being placed in the grid

Comment: Why the spoiler tag here? I don't think that's necessary at all.

Comment: I didn't want to 'spoil' the fun for others. @Deusovi